# Give all elements different background-colors with Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, background-color

I have a table with a variable amound of span-Elements (Bootstrap badges). Some of them have the same ID and some have a different ID. I want each unique span-Element to have a unique color. Those colors should be dark enough to be a good background for white text and they should be as different (colorful) from other elements as possible.

This is where I'm at:
[image]

This is how I apply different background-colors to them with JavaScript:

```
// Find all span elements with .aktiviert in #region-main
const aktiviertSpans = document.querySelectorAll("#region-main .aktiviert");
const idColors = new Map();
let hue = 0;

// loop through all span-elements
for (let i = 0; i < aktiviertSpans.length; i++) {
    const span = aktiviertSpans[i];
    const id = span.id;

    // If the ID exists, give her the existing color
    if (idColors.has(id)) {
        span.style.backgroundColor = idColors.get(id);
    } else {
        // else create a new color
        const color = `hsl(${hue}, 100%, 25%)`;
        idColors.set(id, color);
        span.style.backgroundColor = color;
        hue = (hue + (360 / idColors.size)) % 360;
    }
}
```

Now I have two issues/questions:

1. Is this a good approach or is there a better way? Would it be possible to include bright colors and black text as soon as too many entries exist?
2. For some reason the first two entries get the same background-color "Max" and "Susanne". How can I fix this?

Comment: *"Some of them have the same ID"*: that is not valid in HTML.

Comment: Your color calculations produce a range that is bunched up towards one end of the hue range. You can't determine the right color spread without knowing how many you need first. Split your calculations into three phases: Figure out how many unique colors you need, pick that number of colors, apply the colors.

Comment: @trincot Thank you I didn't think of this. Why does it work though? I'll change it to classes then.

Comment: @Ouroborus The thing is, I don't know how many entries will be created. This Moodle database I'm working on might be used for small groups or for whole classes of 30 studends. Maybe even more. Isn't there a way to spread the color wheel in "X equal parts" where X is a variable? So when I have two entries it will should take two colors with 180° difference.

Comment: Doesn't change anything. You need to know how many entries/colors there needs to be before you can actually start picking what those colors should be.